# Using Automator to batch crop with custom coordinates / measurements

Tags: automator, image-editing, crop

I'm trying to crop large batches of images automatically.  I'm currently using Automator's Crop Images action, but it is lacking in options.  I can specify a width and height, and then it performs a centered crop.  I want to be able to specify X and Y as well as width and height (to use Xcode terms), so I can perform a consistent crop for any custom rectangle.  Are there better, more featureful cropping actions available?  Preferably for free...  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you want with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). Hopefully you’re comfortable using Terminal (and also use Homebrew to manage all your packages).

Either way, you must install ImageMagick so you can run `convert` command line in Terminal.

1. Open the folder you want to batch processing all the images. If your folder name called *images* is located on Desktop, you’ll need to enter `cd ~/Desktop/images/` in Terminal.
2. ImageMagick have a built-in option to crop images according to sizes and coordinates. The command is:

   ```
    convert <input documents> <width>x<height>+<pos x>+<pos y> <output filepath>
   ```

---

### Cropping Images with ImageMagick

If I want to crop all the images into:

- Width: 300px
- Height: 500px
- Position X: 100px from top left
- Position Y: 70px from top left

I can enter the command below:

```
convert *.jpg -crop 300x500+100+70 result/screenshot.jpg
```

---

Make sure the target filepath exists. In this case, you should create a folder called `result` in Desktop. Or you can use absolute path like `~/Desktop/result` or whatever folder you want to point. Just drag the folder into Terminal like this:

[image: Dragging Folder into Terminal]

Comment: I tried this but it only resized one image. It took me a while to work out that the path must include a file name. I wanted the files in `./done`, so had to use result path like `./done/cropped.png` to get files `cropped-0.png`, `cropped-1.png` and so on. How can I keep the original file name?

Comment: Oh, use `mogrify` instead of `convert`.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick `convert` worked for me, but only after I wrapped it in a for-loop:

```
for filename in *.jpg; do\
  convert $filename -crop {height}x{width}+{position-x}+{position-y} "result/$filename"
  echo "$filename done"
done
```